# How to gain more attention on question which should be closed even if flagging didn't help?

Tags: support, questions, flags, vote-to-close, closed-questions

A few days ago I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363228/view-method-information-is-slowly-in-android-studio-and-hao-to-change-the-associ) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296314/semi-transparent-box-with-html-css) as *Unclear what you're asking*, but the reason my flags are still pending might be because of very low number of views. And since I'm not in charge to close it right away, but questions are very poor, so they must be closed. How can I gain more attention to these questions, except flagging?

Comment: *"How can I gain more attention to this questions excepting flagging?"* - you don't, they will go into the appropriate review queues and be dealt with. However, note that there are currently more than 7,000 questions waiting to be closed and it requires five votes to do so, so it may take a while...

Comment: One is closed now, the other should be on its way. If you really feel a question needs some more urgency to gets closed (maybe because they are asked in a low-traffic tag) feel free to drop a `[tag:cv-pls] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296314/semi-transparent-box-with-html-css` in the [SO Close Vote reviewers chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: Making a meta post seems like a good way to get their attention.

Comment: I had the same question, about questions I tagged months ago. Thanks for asking this!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As @rene said in the comments:

> If you really feel a question needs some more urgency to gets closed
> (maybe because they are asked in a low-traffic tag) feel free to drop
> a
>
> ```
> [tag:cv-pls] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296314/semi-transparent-box-with-html-css
> ```
>
> in the [SO Close Vote reviewers chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: ...Why is this CW? I could understand if you'd get any rep from upvotes, but this is Meta.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes That's not the only reason to use CW. In this case I imagine that they want to highlight the fact that the content is not their own, but was gleaned from comments.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Oh, that makes sense. I figured it'd be something incredibly obvious that just didn't occur to me...

Comment: @QPaysTaxes That and sub-2K users can't improve non-CW posts on child meta.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes also badges are still a thing on meta.  Including ones for "rep" like [mortarboard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: the OP might also have forgotten that meta.so is not meta.se, where you *do* get rep

Answer (score 3):

In addition to posting the question in the [CV reviewers chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers):

## Make sure to downvote the question too.

**You do not lose rep for downvoting questions.**

Questions will be [automagically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) when:

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

Questions that are as bad as these ones with negative score are unlikely to get answers, so will be automatically deleted after 30 days **as long as they have no answers and negative score**.

It's more important to get others' attention on these sorts of bad questions *only if they already have answers*; automatic deletion will only occur on questions **with answers** if they are closed.

Comment: yeah, I've met these requirements once :)